# google STT stream with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, speech-to-text

i'm trying to use google STT from asterisk, the idea is to send live stream to google during session, does any one succeed ? any example will be much appreciate

Answer (score -2):

Google cloud speech api have working example of python code for streaming.

Yes, it work just ok, you just need orginize stream from asterisk.

Answer (score -2):

Streaming is complex to integrate, and more in the Asterisk project. The streaming allows to reduce the time processing, but I am not sure that the gain is engouth against the post processing from a record. Voximal doesn't use the streaming mode for example and it works fine. You only need to be sure that you have a good connection to reduce the uploading time.

Comment: Just to update this comment, voximal supports streaming with the gRPC protocol since the Version 14.1.